# iOS - How can I add my own ads (which SDK ?) without third-party networks ?

Tags: ios

I'm trying to put ads into an iOS app. Contrary to the majority of developers, I don't want to use a third party network that's going to pay me (CPM etc.)

The reason is I have a second app which is an online shop that sells the articles I want to promote in the first app.

What I've tried so far:

- Using Appsfire (great SDK and very nice native ads, but requires the developper to use their advertising network)
- Using MoPub (I am a bit confused, I thought the "base SDK" would allow me to use the code without any third-party network, however I can't figure out if I misunderstood or what because I still need unit IDs that I can't obtain (can I ?) without registering an account with bank information.

Do you know if there is some free source code to implement nice ads in custom table views, in a "carousel" such as you can see on Facebook, twitter etc. ?

I feel like I am the only one who does not want to be paid for putting ads in my app thus I only find SDKs with third-partu networks.

(Even a cocoa pod would be fine)

Thank you for your help,

Answer (score 0):

Well, not wanting to sound smartassy, but it sounds like you want a custom solution, so why not write one yourself? It may even be to your benefit, as you can start simple (just display the banners) and add some other fancy things as you go.

I understand the need/desire to find something already done and not reinvent the wheel, but sometimes it is the best way to go.

As to the UI part there is a whole lot of them in cocoapods : [link](http://Well,%20not%20wanting%20to%20sound%20smartassy,%20but%20it%20sounds%20like%20you%20want%20a%20custom%20solution,%20so%20why%20not%20write%20one%20yourself?%20It%20may%20be%20to%20your%20benefit%20also)

Comment: Hi, yeah sure I could write one myself, but it might take a bit longer and let's say someday I change my mind and want to use a third party network, it would be easier then !